# No sound is heard when making outgoing call with PJSIP sample code for Android version

Tags: android, pjsip

I am the new developer for PJSIP android version. (Android version 4.4)

I am testing the PJSIP android sample application got from PJSIP official website.

The incoming call works normally while no sound is heard when making an outgoing call.

I checked the logs and find the application does not set the sound device when making an outgoing call. (Actually, it did, I just missed the logs in the beginning of making an outgoing call.)

[The log of making outgoing call](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mub8uuvasx3t9oy/20170417_PJSIP_MakeCallLog_Android.txt?dl=0)

[The log of receiving a call](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekxv52nzhr2d7s1/20170417_PJSIP_IncomingCallLog_Android.txt?dl=0)

I find that there is a message that might be the reason causes no audio in the outgoing call.

```
sound_port.c  EC suspended because of inactivity
```

But I still don't know why there is no audio when making an outgoing call.
Could anyone have any idea how to solve this or give me more directions to check this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How you make the call? Do you set the CallOpParam and the CallSetting?

If not try the following:

```
CallOpParam callOpParam = new CallOpParam(true);
CallSetting callSetting = new CallSetting();
callSetting.setAudioCount(1);
//callSetting.setVideoCount(1); //If you want video 
callOpParam.setOpt(callSetting);
Call call = new Call(account);
call.makeCall("destination", callOpParam);
```

For better help, can you put the code of how you make the call and how you answer the call?

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.

I find it is the NAT issue that causes RTP connection unavailable.

I set the SIP server on the same domain and the application works normally.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify this as I am also facing the same issue